Why Eclipse doesn't recognize my class which one is for Junit testing?
I am facing a issue that even my Junit class doesn't give an error, Eclipse doesn't run my junit test(I am super new in Junit Testing but, i guess eclipse doesn't recognize my junit test methods.
here my pom.xml ;
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>otopark-yonetim</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>otopark-yonetim</name>
    <description>otopark yonetimi icin web projesi</description>
    <url />
    <licenses>
        <license />
    </licenses>
    <developers>
        <developer />
    </developers>
    <scm>
        <connection />
        <developerConnection />
        <tag />
        <url />
    </scm>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.giffing.bucket4j.spring.boot.starter</groupId>
            <artifactId>bucket4j-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Jackson Dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Jakarta Servlet Dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring Boot Starter Web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JUnit 5 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring Boot Starter Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Mockito -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring Boot DevTools -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>



and my project architecture looks like;
project_architecture
my AracService in an abstract class and here my class for junit tesing AracServiceTest;
package com.example.otopark_yonetim.services;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;

import com.example.otopark_yonetim.entities.Arac;
import com.example.otopark_yonetim.repositories.AracRepository;

import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

/**
 * 
 */
@SpringBootTest
class AracServiceTest {

    @Mock
    private AracRepository aracRepository;

    @InjectMocks
    private AracService aracService;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
        aracService = new AracService(aracRepository) {
            @Override
            public double fiyatHesapla(long id) {
                return 50.0;
            }
        };
    }

    @Test
    void testAracGirisYapti() {
        String plaka = "34XYZ12";
        String aracTuru = "Otomobil";

        Arac mockArac = Arac.builder().plaka(plaka).aracTuru(aracTuru).girisSaati(LocalDateTime.now()).icerde(true)
                .build();

        when(aracRepository.save(any(Arac.class))).thenReturn(mockArac);

        Arac sonuc = aracService.aracGirisYapti(plaka, aracTuru);

        assertNotNull(sonuc);
        assertEquals(plaka, sonuc.getPlaka());
        assertEquals(aracTuru, sonuc.getAracTuru());
        assertTrue(sonuc.isIcerde());
        verify(aracRepository, times(1)).save(any(Arac.class));
    }

    @Test
    void testHesaplaDakikaFarki() {
        LocalDateTime giris = LocalDateTime.now().minusMinutes(30);
        LocalDateTime cikis = LocalDateTime.now();

        double fark = aracService.hesaplaDakikaFarki(giris, cikis);

        assertEquals(30.0, fark, 0.01);
    }

    @Test
    void testAracCikisYapti() {
        // Arrange
        long aracId = 1L;
        Arac mockArac = new Arac();
        mockArac.setId(aracId);
        mockArac.setIcerde(true);

        when(aracRepository.findById(aracId)).thenReturn(java.util.Optional.of(mockArac));
        when(aracRepository.save(mockArac)).thenReturn(mockArac);

        // Act
        Arac sonuc = aracService.aracCikisYapti(aracId);

        // Assert
        assertNotNull(sonuc);
        assertFalse(sonuc.isIcerde());
        verify(aracRepository, times(1)).findById(aracId);
        verify(aracRepository, times(1)).save(mockArac);
    }
}


is there any idea, where is my problem?
I tried to clean and update the project but it couldn't be helpful.

Can you check defining the test class as public?

Can you include how it is you're trying to run your tests?

Your test should be in src/test/ava not src/test/resources. resources is for non java files. Also the @SpringBootTest on your test doesn't make sense as you are not using anything Spring related in your tests only mockito.

You must not use @SpringBootTest and @Mock/@InjectMocks annotations together. One starts the application context and wires beans, the other creates Mockito mock instances (not registered as Spring beans, they live outside the application context)

@M.Deinum Please add it as an answer. Note, in your comment you have a typo: src/test/java without j.

You have placed your test in src/test/resources which is the location for non-java files. Your tests should be placed in src/test/java (just as regular java goes in src/main/java).
